# Generic function using an abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, static, abstract-class

I am trying to create a static function replacing the instance of an abstract class by an other one. (I simplified the code to focus on where it does not work) :

```
abstract class AbstractData
{
    public int MaxValue;
    public int[] GivenValues;
}

static class AnalyzeData
{
    static void Analyze<T>(int limitValue, AbstractData abstractData) where T : AbstractData
    {
        T.GivenValues = abstractData.GivenValues; //error : T is a type parameter which is not valid in the given context
        T.MaxValue= abstractData.GivenValues[0]; // same error
        foreach (var data in abstractData.GivenValues)
        {
           if (data<limitValue){
               T.MaxValue = data;
           }
        }
        abstractData = T; //same error
    }
}
```

I have tried to replace T by AbstractData in the definition of the function, or to cast T, but non of that worked.

The only solution I have found is to use an other instance of Abstract Data as parameter (and having 'in' and 'out' instances) :

```
static void Analyze<T>(int limitValue, AbstractData abstractDataIn, AbstractData abstractDataOut)
```

But then I would lose the advantage of the generic part of the function.

Do you know why I have this error, and how I can correct it?

Thx !

Comment: I don't see the use case of generics here. Pass in two `AbstractData`, the first is the source and the second is the target. Generic type arguments aren't instances of it.

Comment: I want to use the data in the source to modify the target, and then the target has to replace the source in a list<Data1> or list<Data2>. I need the user only run the analysis on the values in the list that he wants, without having to care if he is runing the analysis on Data1 or Data2 instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is a `Type`, not an instance of a type. If you want to create and return a new instance, you have to write that like this:

```
static T Analyze<T>(int limitValue, AbstractData abstractData) where T : AbstractData, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    t.GivenValues = abstractData.GivenValues;
    t.MaxValue= abstractData.GivenValues[0];
    foreach (var data in abstractData.GivenValues)
    {
       if (data<limitValue){
           t.MaxValue = data;
       }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Where you have the return value of type `T`.

Another option is to pass in an instance of `T`:

```
static void Analyze<T>(int limitValue, AbstractData abstractData, T t) where T : AbstractData
{
    t.GivenValues = abstractData.GivenValues;
    t.MaxValue= abstractData.GivenValues[0];
    foreach (var data in abstractData.GivenValues)
    {
       if (data<limitValue){
           t.MaxValue = data;
       }
    }
}
```

Then there is no need to `return` the newly created instance.

Comment: The issue with this, is that if I have two classes inheriting from AbstractData (Data1 and Data2 for example, the user can call "Analyze<Data2> (limitValue, Data1)"
I want to ensure that the two instances are from the same class (Data1 or Data2)

Comment: Then only use `T`. In that way, you can be sure both are always of the same type.

Comment: So replace `AbstractData abstractData` with `T t2`.